# PhoneScreenVerticalManager weirdness on incoming call

Tags: java, blackberry

Im making an app which has a listener on incoming calls and then adds fields til the phonescreen..
However i cannot seem to really control the width of either labelfields or the PhoneScreenVerticalManager i use.
If i try to set a border or background on the PhoneScreenVerticalManager nothing happens at all.
It also seems like USE_ALL_WIDTH in the labelfield constructor doesn't change anything.
And getting the labelfields to left align i also couldn't get to work (tried DrawStyle.Left in the labelfield constructor).

here is my code:

```
public Incoming(int callId) {     
     this.callId = callId;
     PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);  
  String number = call.getPhoneNumber();
  Vector contact = ContactUtil.getContactByPhone(number); 
        screenModel = new ScreenModel(callId);
        phoneScreenPortrait = screenModel.getPhoneScreen(PhoneScreen.PORTRAIT, PhoneScreen.INCOMING);
        final XYRect rect = screenModel.getDimensions(PhoneScreen.PORTRAIT, PhoneScreen.INCOMING);
 PhoneScreenVerticalManager manager = new PhoneScreenVerticalManager()
         {

          public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                 g.clear();
                 super.paint(g);
             }

          protected void sublayout(int width, int height)
             {
                 super.sublayout(rect.width, height);
                 super.setExtent(rect.width, height);
             }

         };        

         manager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));
         manager.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(BORDER_PADDING, BORDER_PADDING, BORDER_PADDING, BORDER_PADDING), Border.STYLE_SOLID));

         String s = res.getString(FOUND_IN_CONTACTS);
         LabelField header = new LabelField(s, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
         {
          protected void layout(int width, int height)
             {
                 super.layout(rect.width, height);
                 setExtent(rect.width, height);
             }

          public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                 g.clear();
                 super.paint(g);
             }
         };
         header.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
         manager.add(header);
         LabelField label = new LabelField(contact.firstElement().toString(), LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
         {
          protected void layout(int width, int height)
             {
                 super.layout(rect.width, height);
                 setExtent(rect.width, height);
             }

          public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                 g.clear();
                 super.paint(g);
             }

         };
         label.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
         manager.add(label);
         phoneScreenPortrait.add(manager);
        screenModel.sendAllDataToScreen();
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!¨

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

though the phonescreen managers are derived from the field manager it doesn't support all the field manager properties.

so the solution is to set up normal field manager and then add those to the phonescreen managers